# Java. Вопрос по многопоточности

Tags: java, многопоточность, concurrency

Возьмем классический пример:

```
public class Keeper {

    volatile Data data = null;

    public Data getData() {
        if(data == null) 
            synchronized(this) {
                if(data == null)
                    data = new Data();
            }
        return data;
    }
}
```

Насколько я понимаю этот пример не совсем корректный с точки зрения JMM.

А именно тут происходит 2 чтения `volatile` переменной `data` уже после ее создания:

1. первый условный оператор в коде `if(data == null)`
2. и `return data`.

И если я правильно понял доклад Алексея Шипилева, может возникнуть ситуация когда в первом чтении мы прочитаем не `null`, а во втором чтении может быть `null`. Но к сожалению я не совсем понимаю почему так может произойти с `volatile` переменной.

Не могли ли бы вы объяснить с доказательством почему такая ситуация возможна.

Спасибо.

Comment: Так вроде и не может, вот [статья](https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/safe-public-construction/#_safe_publication) Шипилёва 2014 года, там пример разобран (`SafeDCLFactory`, только у вас `private` на поле не хватает). Но [можно убрать](https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/close-encounters-of-jmm-kind/#wishful-benign-is-resilient) `volatile`, если сделать одно чтение и объект `Data` безопасно инициализирован (все его поля `final`).

Comment: ссылку-то на доклад добавили бы, а то мы не знаем, какой тезис разбираем

Comment: видел на jokere, ссылку добавить не могу к сожалению(

Comment: наверно я все же не так понял, скорее всего там не было volatile так как пример был чуть другой.

Comment: [слайды](https://shipilev.net/talks/joker-Oct2016-jmm-close-encounters.pdf) вот есть

Comment: да, спасибо. С примером я ошибся конечно, вот сейчас посмотрел и вспомнил. И так пример на слайде: 46. Я не знаю как его лучше сюда вставить. Могу конечно поправить пост, но не уверен что это правильно. Так вот там в примере доказывается, что val может принять null. И вот почему так если туда все же было записано значение я понять не могу

Comment: то есть там в примере получается, что val может быть равен null, хотя supp != EMPTY, а значит в val в volatile переменную была запись и в таком случаи как мы можем ее не видеть?

Comment: если вот это случилось: (,  )
hb
−−→ (, ) , значит в volatile же есть значения и потоки должны его видеть?

Comment: Согласно JMM, разные потоки могут наблюдать разный порядок выполнения для одних и тех же действий, если действия не связаны с потоками через happens-before. Т.е. второй поток может увидеть _w(supp, E)_ раньше, чем _w(val, V)_.

Comment: Предположу (предположу!), что несмотря на hb, `val = supp.get()` и `supp = EMPTY` могут физически иметь противоположный порядок. Сам hb будет наблюдаться только в том треде, который попал в synchronized-блок, потому что устанавливается только для этих двух операций.

Comment: Я даже, пожалуй, приложу [цитату](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5): More specifically, if two actions share a _happens-before_ relationship, they do not necessarily have to appear to have happened in that order to any code with which they do not share a _happens-before_ relationship. Writes in one thread that are in a data race with reads in another thread may, for example, appear to occur out of order to those reads.